# Why does including a header using the full path lead to better error messages?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

There was a recent post on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/611400/158442), where OP was trying to compile a program which included `term.h`. When the code had `#include <term.h>`, the errors were:

```
In file included from clear_screen_UNIX.c:5:0:
clear_screen_UNIX.c:9:6: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘->’ token
 void clear_screen(void) {
      ^
clear_screen_UNIX.c: In function ‘main’:
clear_screen_UNIX.c:23:14: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
  clear_screen();
              ^
clear_screen_UNIX.c:26:14: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
  clear_screen();
```

The OP then included the full path to `term.h` (`#include "/usr/include/term.h"`), which led to the much more useful message:

```
In file included from clear_screen_UNIX.c:7:0:
/usr/include/term.h:125:21: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘->’ token
 #define CUR cur_term->type.
                     ^
/usr/include/term.h:202:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘CUR’
 #define clear_screen                   CUR Strings[5]
                                        ^
clear_screen_UNIX.c:9:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘clear_screen’
 void clear_screen(void) {
      ^
clear_screen_UNIX.c: In function ‘main’:
clear_screen_UNIX.c:23:14: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
  clear_screen();
              ^
clear_screen_UNIX.c:26:14: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
  clear_screen();
```

These messages clearly indicate the problem is due to a macro expansion.

I verified the results myself, too. I wonder why GCC produced much better errors when the full path was given. Can I make it produce similar messages with the system include syntax as well?

I am using GCC 4.9.2, and I suspect OP was using GCC 4.8.2 (given the version of Ubuntu).

Comment: looks like a gcc bug to me

Comment: @user2225104 Honestly, I don't code in C (and by extension, use GCC or other C compilers) often enough to know the expected behaviour here.

Comment: What happens if you use llvm/clang instead?

Comment: @uchuugaka dunno, I don't have a system with clang handy. I'll update once I have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Conclusion

The reason GCC gives different/better messages if the full path of the header is given is that the GCC preprocessor gives information to GCC's  `cc1` compiler that the included header is a system header file or local header file by some digits at the end of the comment line of the preprocessor-generated `.i` file.

Then the `cc1` compiler will generate more helpful messages if the header file is an local header file, and will suppress some error message if the header file is a system header, according to the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html).

To make the normal version of the code output error messages just like the code which specified the full path of the header file, as you asked for,  GCC needs to stop including all system directories by specifying option `-nostdinc`, and then explicitly tell GCC the directories it could search for header files while not treat the directory as system directory using `-I` flag.

For your code, the command line could be like below (`GCC_INCLUDE_DIR` is your default GCC include directory, for the system default GCC, it could be `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/`) :

```
gcc -c t.c -nostdinc -I/usr/include/ -IGCC_INCLUDE_DIR
```

#### Source code

<sub><sup>Moved the source code here from [this original post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611400/how-to-compile-programs-that-use-term-h) to make this answer more helpful.</sup></sub>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <term.h>

//#include "/usr/include/term.h"

void clear_screen(void) {
    if (!cur_term) {
        int result;
        setupterm( NULL, STDOUT_FILENO, &result );
    if (result <= 0)
        return;
    }

    putp( tigetstr( "clear" ) );
}

int main(void) {
    puts("I am going to clear the screen");
    sleep(1);
    clear_screen();
    puts("Screen Cleared");
    sleep(1);
    clear_screen();

    return 0;

}
```

### The difference between Preprocessor Generated Files

You could use the following command line to ask GCC to output the preproceser generated code. This code will be fed into the actual compiler of GCC, `cc1`. If the preprocessor generated files are exactly the same, the `cc1` compiler's behavior  should be exactly the same. (Assuming the code is put into file `t.c`)

```
 gcc -E t.c -o t.i
```

Following is the difference between the two gcc preprocessor generated `.i` files. The `t.fullpath.i` is the file generated with the full path header file, while `t.i` is the code without full path (Some of the `diff` output have been removed, since they are only filename differences.)

```
$ diff t.i t.fullpath.i
2920,2922c2920,2924
< # 1 "/usr/include/term.h" 1 3 4
< # 47 "/usr/include/term.h" 3 4
---
> # 1 "/usr/include/term.h" 1
> # 47 "/usr/include/term.h"
2924,2925c2926,2927
< # 48 "/usr/include/term.h" 2 3 4
< # 80 "/usr/include/term.h" 3 4
---
> # 48 "/usr/include/term.h" 2
> # 80 "/usr/include/term.h"
3007,3008c3009,3010
< # 81 "/usr/include/term.h" 2 3 4
< # 673 "/usr/include/term.h" 3 4
---
> # 81 "/usr/include/term.h" 2
> # 673 "/usr/include/term.h"
3041c3043
< # 729 "/usr/include/term.h" 3 4
---
> # 729 "/usr/include/term.h"
```

The different flag in the preprocessor generated code's comments makes the difference

GCC's `cc1` compiler will take advantage of the preprocessor genrated information to generate the source code location of the error message, and also the debug information which will be used for gdb in the future.

For the following format:

```
# line-number "source-file" [flags]
```

The digits `3` and `4` of the flags mean:

- 3: Following text comes from a system header file (`#include <>` vs `#include ""`)
- 4: Following text should be treated as being wrapped in an implicit `extern "C"` block.

  For more information about different kind of these flags, please refer to [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html).

Therefore, for the code without fully specified path, `cc1` compiler will treat it as a system header file, and assume that system code is mostly correct, and then just output error message of the user's code. That is why the error message is shorter.

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't the diff output suggest the opposite? (The numbers next to the filenames are removed - less information!) O.o So is there a flag somewhere I can use to make `cpp` include more information?

Comment: That makes sense. So no way to make `cpp` skip those flags except using the full path?

Comment: No, `-Wsystem-headers` makes no difference.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect msg, you should use `-nostdinc -ISYSTEM_DIR` options. Please refer to the latest version of my above answer for details. @muru

Comment: FWIW, [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html) is the gcc doc page that describes this behavior.  In particular, you might want to note the effects of #pragma GCC system_header, which forces this behavior regardless of the directory the file was found in.

Comment: Still looks like a bug to me lol.  I would consider a switch like ``-allow_cryptic_error_messages_for_standard_headers`` to be a well thought-out feature, in contrast :)

Comment: Whether you want to call this a bug or a feature in gcc, if you feel that Kun has answered your question about why this happens, you should accept his answer so he gets credit for his work.